# missing 7 required positional arguments

Tags: python, scipy

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def f(theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4,beta1,beta2,beta3,beta4):
    func1 = -0.07*beta1*theta1**2/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta1*theta2**2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.07*beta1*theta3**2/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.07*beta1*theta4**2/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta1/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta1/(-theta1 + 1) - 1.86*theta1/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.93*theta2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.93*theta3/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.93*theta4/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) + 0.93*(-theta1 + 0.93)/(theta1**2 - 1) - 0.93/(-theta1 + 1)
    func2 = -0.07*beta2*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.07*beta2*theta2**2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta2*theta3**2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.07*beta2*theta4**2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta2/(-theta2 + 1) - 0.06*theta1/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.12*theta2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.06*theta3/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.06*theta4/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) + 0.06*(-theta1 + 0.93)/(theta1*theta2 - 1) - 0.06/(-theta2 + 1),
    func3 = -0.07*beta3*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.07*beta3*theta2**2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.07*beta3*theta3**2/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta3*theta4**2/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta3/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta3/(-theta3 + 1) - 0.001*theta1/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.001*theta2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.002*theta3/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.001*theta4/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) + 0.001*(-theta1 + 0.93)/(theta1*theta3 - 1) - 0.001/(-theta3 + 1),
    func4 = -0.07*beta4*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta4*theta2**2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta4*theta3**2/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.07*beta4*theta4**2/(-theta4**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta4/(-theta4**2 + 1) - 0.07*beta4/(-theta4 + 1) - 0.003*theta1/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.003*theta2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.003*theta3/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.006*theta4/(-theta4**2 + 1) + 0.003*(-theta1 + 0.93)/(theta1*theta4 - 1) - 0.003/(-theta4 + 1),
    func5 = -0.09*beta1*theta1**2/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta1*theta2**2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.09*beta1*theta3**2/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.09*beta1*theta4**2/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta1/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta1/(-theta1 + 1) - 0.12*theta1/(-theta1**2 + 1) - 0.06*theta2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.06*theta3/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.06*theta4/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) + 0.06*(-theta2 + 0.95)/(theta1*theta2 - 1) - 0.06/(-theta1 + 1),
    func6 = -0.09*beta2*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 0.09*beta2*theta2**2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta2*theta3**2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.09*beta2*theta4**2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta2/(-theta2 + 1) - 0.95*theta1/(-theta1*theta2 + 1) - 1.9*theta2/(-theta2**2 + 1) - 0.95*theta3/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.95*theta4/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) + 0.95*(-theta2 + 0.95)/(theta2**2 - 1) - 0.95/(-theta2 + 1),
    func7 = -0.09*beta3*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.09*beta3*theta2**2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.09*beta3*theta3**2/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta3*theta4**2/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta3/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta3/(-theta3 + 1) - 0.03*theta1/(-theta1*theta3 + 1) - 0.03*theta2/(-theta2*theta3 + 1) - 0.06*theta3/(-theta3**2 + 1) - 0.03*theta4/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) + 0.03*(-theta2 + 0.95)/(theta2*theta3 - 1) - 0.03/(-theta3 + 1),
    func8 = -0.09*beta4*theta1**2/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta4*theta2**2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta4*theta3**2/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.09*beta4*theta4**2/(-theta4**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta4/(-theta4**2 + 1) - 0.09*beta4/(-theta4 + 1) - 0.23*theta1/(-theta1*theta4 + 1) - 0.23*theta2/(-theta2*theta4 + 1) - 0.23*theta3/(-theta3*theta4 + 1) - 0.46*theta4/(-theta4**2 + 1) + 0.23*(-theta2 + 0.95)/(theta2*theta4 - 1) - 0.23/(-theta4 + 1)
    return func1,func2,func3,func4,func5,func6,func7,func8

x0 = [0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.8,0.6,0.5,0.7]
result = fsolve(f,x0)
```

I am trying to solve the equations above, but it shows:

> TypeError: f() missing 7 required positional arguments: 'theta2', 'theta3', 'theta4', 'beta1', 'beta2', 'beta3', and 'beta4'

. Any ideas about what I am doing wrong and what I should do to solve the problem?

Comment: `fsolve` calls your function `f` with `x0` as the first argument. It is missing the rest. You should be calling `fsolve` with atleast 3 parameters where the 3rd one is the list of arguments supplied to `f`. Read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html)

Comment: You must pass the seven values to the function or try redefining your function with one array value.

Comment: This is a great help, thanks for your kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two changes to make this work.

1. Change the function to:

   ```
   def f(x0):
       theta1, theta2, theta3, theta4, beta1, beta2, beta3, beta4 = x0
   ```
2. Remove the trailing commas from your `funcX` lines

Then the result is:

```
[-0.30288717 -0.42512799 -0.42004936 -0.41683512 -0.06015582  0.09188239
  0.00146244  0.00425686]
```